# Draw2d JS limited connection of ports

Tags: javascript, html, json, canvas, draw2d

I have a Json file from which information is taken regarding the creation of flowcharts on canvas. The problem is that I want to limit the possible port connections. For example: There is a circuit that has a port named "localID" and I want to connect ports only with a block diagram that also has ports named "localID"

[What the menu looks like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRWoB.png)

```
[
    {
        "name": "asd",
        "id": "",
        "text": "dfg",
        "io": [
            "test",
            "test3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "asdqw",
        "id": "",
        "text": "qsee",
        "io": [
            "fghf",
            "dsrg"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "qqwedwef",
        "id": "",
        "text": "321",
        "io": []
    },
    {enter image description here
        "name": "gjftyuj",
        "id": "",
        "text": "123",
        "io": []
    }
]
```

i try to write a id to end port or start and get only errors, so i decieded to ask my problem here